# Access nested list elements in jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a specific task and the aim is to create PDF report from java.util.Collection list elements. Size of the list is not predefined also nested list size, which is also java.util.Collection list, is not predefined. Each report I have to print in new page. So in the end I need to have one PDF file on meany lists.

The problem is that I cannot access nested list elements

I made subreport for nested list elements,

```
<subreport isUsingCache="false" runToBottom="true">
    <reportElement uuid="23bd89bf-ac96-4a86-8d78-55e07d8bd280" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="64" width="555" height="651"/>
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{records})]]></dataSourceExpression>
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{PaymentDetailsSubReport}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

$F{records} data field must be data array from the nested list. 
I cannot figure out the way how to access nested list elements. 
I found article about field mapping http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/527663/context-help-access-getters 
but is doesn't work in this case

Any idea how to access nested list elements?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution to this?